# Windows batch - where does this command write?

Tags: cmd

I used this command in a windows command line:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>C:\Windows\System32\ForFiles.exe /P C:\myfolder\mysubfolder /S /M *.* /D +09/15/2022 /C "cmd /C echo @FSIZE >> sizes.txt"
```

I wanted to echo all the sizes for files in folder modified in the last 5 days.

I didn't found the output file.

I then solved the problem by changing the command to:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>C:\Windows\System32\ForFiles.exe /P C:\myfolder\mysubfolder /S /M *.* /D +09/15/2022 /C "cmd /C echo @FSIZE" > sizes.txt
```

Anyway, I'd like to know if I created a `sizes.txt` file somewhere on my hard drive.

Searched in the folder, subfolder, desktop, home folder, C:, C:\Windows, C:\Windows\System32... nothing...

Comment: `dir /s /b c:\sizes.txt` - get some off-screen time while while it works...

Comment: for as "where does it write to?": it writes to the current working folder, which with your first code line should have been `C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\sizes.txt`. When no matching files are found or there is a syntax error or if the date format doesn't match the format on your system, no file will be created.

Comment: ```"cmd /C echo @FSIZE"``` is not exactly correct for the task you have described. You should be using something more like this, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\myfolder\mysubfolder" /S /D "+09/15/2022" /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C \"If @ISDIR == FALSE Echo @FSIZE\"" 1>> "sizes.txt"``` to append to an exising file in the current working directory. If you wanted it to create new file content only, you'd change `>>` to `>`. The important part here is that despite its name, the command also includes directories, hence the use of `"If @ISDIR == FALSE`.

Comment: @Stephan That where I expected to find it, but no... I finally found them, yes "them". One in each directory containing recently edited file(s). Seems that the command forfiles executes is actually run where the file is located.

Comment: Uhh - I guess there is a (bunch of) reason(s) why `forfiles` is used so rarely...  `:D`

Comment: @Stephan It's strange because if you specify `echo %CD%` as command it actually prints desktop!

Comment: yes - `forfiles` is ... what should I name it? ...  alien?.

Comment: @Teejay, your command was writing to the parent of each matching file, because you were not correctly using doublequotes. What you've affectively written, _(corrected)_, is ```%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\myfolder\mysubfolder" /S /D "+09/15/2022" /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C \"If @ISDIR == FALSE Echo @FSIZE 1^>^>\"Sizes.log\"\""```. Essentially the `ForFiles` command performs a behind the scenes directory change for each match, which I see as a feature, not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found them, yes "them".

One in each directory containing recently edited file(s).

Seems that the command `forfiles` executes is actually run where the file is located.

It's strange because if you specify `cmd /C echo %CD%` as command it actually prints the directory you run from, in my case Desktop!